# How to create an alert on Hazelcast replicated map

Tags: java, replication, hazelcast

We have a couple of Hazelcast instances in one cluster and 20 replicated maps in each one.  We have also lots of Hazelcast clients that reading data from those replicated maps.

The project has performance criteria so each get operation to map cannot last for more than 2 milliseconds. We want to track that criteria and create alert and interrupt the get operation on each replicated map if it takes more than 2 milliseconds.

However we cannot add timeout to replicated map get operation unlike Imap(it has getAsync). Also we cannot create filter from management center as it does not provide replicated map option as seen in image below:

[image: Hazelcast Management Center alert tab]

**In short, how to create an alert on replicated map and adding timeout programmatically if possible?**

Comment: Have you considered using IMap+near cache on clients instead? If you're using replicated map I'm assuming data is mostly-read. In those cases where read ratio is much higher than write ratio, near cache on clients can give you a massive performance boost. Furthermore, you can achieve what you want by using async methods, give it 2ms timeout and catch the timeout exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.hazelcast.core.EntryListener` on a ReplicatedMap. See here for details: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#using-entrylistener-on-replicated-map

Comment: I think this answer should be a comment. And in question, he or she wants to now how to make an alert on replicated map with hazelcast management center. There is no datatype for replicated map. Read carefully.

Comment: As far as I read, it is not possible to add timeout with entry listener. Also, entry listener does not catch get operation.

Comment: @drowny where in question it said “alert with Management Centre”? You should read the question again, and carefully.

Comment: @wildnez you can see photo clearly which is choosen with red square.

Comment: @sarah yes, ReplicateMap does not provide timeout on get operation. Also, there are no event listener for get operations.

Comment: @drowny I am not going to debate with you on the validity of the question.